# Consumers from Rabbit were stopped and never recover

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

My spring boot application has been running with no erros during months using RabbitMq. In the last weeks, my consumer stopped working and I have to restart my application. Everyday I have to restart the application.

I noticed that it happens after this error in my log:

```
    24-07-2021 07:20:08.138 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
24-07-2021 07:20:08.295 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - IO Error: Socket read interrupted, Authentication lapse 682 ms.
24-07-2021 07:20:10.608 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'protected void br.jus.tjmg.certidaoEmissao.application.queues.EmissaoCriminalHistoricaConsumer.processaMensagem(br.jus.tjmg.certidao.webservice.ConsultaCertidoesRequest)' threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1366)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:848)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:832)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1073)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:450)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at br.jus.tjmg.certidaoEmissao.application.services.EmissaoCertidaoService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46f4e1c7.atualizarExecucaoCertidao(<generated>)
    at br.jus.tjmg.certidaoEmissao.application.queues.EmissaoCriminalHistoricaConsumer.processaMensagem(EmissaoCriminalHistoricaConsumer.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:190)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:162)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:400)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read interrupted, Authentication lapse 682 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:794)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:384)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:273)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:198)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Socket read interrupted, Authentication lapse 682 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:790)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket read interrupted
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:152)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOHeader.readHeaderBuffer(NIOHeader.java:82)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:139)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:101)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:80)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForReading(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:98)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:534)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:485)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:499)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1279)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:663)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
24-07-2021 07:20:20.230 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Stopping container from aborted consumer
24-07-2021 07:20:20.525 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Waiting for workers to finish.
24-07-2021 07:20:20.584 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Successfully waited for workers to finish.
```

I would like to avoid my consumer gets down. I have tried many different solutions, for example to restart my application after some events, but they didn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    context = SpringApplication.run(CertidaoApplication.class, args);
}

public static void restart() {
    ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        context.close();
        context = SpringApplication.run(CertidaoApplication.class, args.getSourceArgs());
    });

    thread.setDaemon(false);
    thread.start();
}

@EventListener
public void handleEvent(ListenerContainerConsumerTerminatedEvent e) {
    logger.info("Restart spring boot. ListenerContainerConsumerTerminatedEvent");
    CertidaoApplication.restart();
}

@EventListener
public void handleEvent(ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent e) {
    logger.info("Restart spring boot. ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent");
    CertidaoApplication.restart();
}

@EventListener
public void handleEvent(ContextStoppedEvent e) {
    logger.info("Restart spring boot. ContextStoppedEvent");
    CertidaoApplication.restart();
}

@EventListener
public void handleEvent(ContextClosedEvent e) {
    logger.info("Restart spring boot. ContextClosedEvent");
    CertidaoApplication.restart();
}
```

Here my configuration:

```
@Bean
public RabbitListenerContainerFactory<SimpleMessageListenerContainer> prefetchRabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    factory.setPrefetchCount(2);
    factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(Boolean.FALSE);
    factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    factory.setMissingQueuesFatal(Boolean.FALSE);
    return factory;
}
```

My consumer:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${queue}", concurrency = "1", containerFactory = "prefetchRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
protected void processMessage(ConsultaRequest message) {
    logger.info("Test" + message.getNumber());
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See stack trace: your error is fully not related to Rabbit MQ or Spring AMQP. More over I don't think there is any problem with Spring at all. It looks like you have some authentication problems connecting to your Oracle DB via that `JpaTransactionManager`, which happens already downstream in your `EmissaoCriminalHistoricaConsumer.processaMensagem(br.jus.tjmg.certidao.webservice.ConsultaCertidoesRequest)` method call.

Comment: Sometimes I have this error, but it doesn't cause my consumer to stop. Is there a way to keep my consumer up even with this error?

Comment: OK. Then this stack trace is not related to the problem. Sorry for misunderstanding your concern. I see 10 seconds gap between that exception and such an error with TX.

Comment: You don't show more logs over there. We can get `Stopping container from aborted consumer` only if `aborted` state is `true which comes with some extra logs for a reason. On the other hand: would you mind upgrading to the latest Spring AMQP: https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp#learn ?

Comment: I have no more errors. I'm using 2.1.0.RELEASE.

Comment: That's too old and out of support version. I'm definitely curious if you can upgrade and observer the same problem...

Comment: Ok, I will do that.

Comment: I could not upgrade de version of Spring AMQP because of the many others libs.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, is there a way to start my consumer automatically? Maybe I can use listener:
        retry:
            enabled: true
            max-attempts: 10
            max-interval: 20000

Comment: That's not related to that sporadic stop. I also can't say what is going on with that old version.  Perhaps if you can come up with a simple project to let us play on our side and reproduce, so then I can say you what is the cause and provide some workaround.