# How to handleCancel consumer with SimpleRabbitListenerContainer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Considering the unsolved question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531054/consumers-from-rabbit-were-stopped-and-never-recover?noredirect=1#comment121120850_68531054), I would like to do something related to handleCancel.

```
channel.queueDeclare(queue, false, true, false, null);
Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
@Override
public void handleCancel(String consumerTag) throws IOException {
    // consumer has been cancelled unexpectedly
}};
```

How can I do that with SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `@EventListener` for an `AsyncConsumerStoppedEvent`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#consumer-events

Comment: Can I use AsyncConsumerTerminatedEvent?

Comment: There is no such event; you can use `ListenerContainerConsumerTerminatedEvent` but that is only published when a fatal error occurs; a cancel is not immediately fatal. A cancel is received if the queue is deleted while we are listening. The container will retry to listen 3 times at 5 second intervals (by default) and only then will the `ListenerContainerConsumerTerminatedEvent` be published.